# Understanding というのは after a dash?

Tags: grammar, translation

> 姫子「というわけで二学期もこれで終わりだ」
>
> 姫子「明日からは冬休みだが、羽目を外さないように」
>
> 姫子「**ーーというのは**、毎年言われているだろうから深くは掘り下げん」
>
> 姫子「課題と共に無事に戻ってこい。よい冬休みを。以上だ」

The teacher 姫子 is addressing the students.

How should I understand the というのは in this context? And can I translate 毎年言われているだろうから深くは掘り下げん as "You students are told not to have too much fun every year, so I will not delve deeper"? Is anything wrong with the translation?

Answer (score 3):

The dashes indicate a pause before the character speaks.

From [this guide](https://lifelikewriter.com/dash-and-leader/#st-toc-h-13)

> 「間（空白）」を演出する

As for the translation, your understanding is fine. というのは quotes the preceding 羽目を外さないように=*Don't have too much fun*, in the way similar to *which is...* in English. So the more literal translation may be: *...which I guess is what you are told every year, so I don't say more about it (=how you shouldn't have too much fun)*.